# Xsp2 and multiple applications - can't get working

Tags: mono, virtual, hosts, xsp2

I try to setup xsp2 webserver to serve multiple applications.

Created the configuration file sites.webapp

```
<apps>
   <web-application>
        <name>app1</name>
        <vhost>domain1.com</vhost>
        <vport>8080</vport>
        <vpath>/</vpath>
        <path>/var/www/app1</path>
   </web-application>
   <web-application>
        <name>app2</name>
        <vhost>domain2.com</vhost>
        <vport>8080</vport>
        <vpath>/</vpath>
        <path>/var/www/app2</path>
   </web-application>
</apps>
```

Then I start the server 
`xsp2 --appconfigfile site.webapp`

http://domain1.com:8080  shows a page from app2.
http://domain2.com:8080 shows the same page from app2.

Seems the xsp2 uses the last application from sites.webapp and serves all requests with it.

What am I doing wrong? Please help to setup multiple virtual hosts for xsp2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer for my question. Support of multiple hosts is not implemented in xsp2.

Comment: Where did you find your answer? It would be good to share it with anyone who comes across this same question.